# OpenERP how to add employee as team members in project management?

Tags: odoo, project-management, openerp-7

Just I have installed OpenERP Project Management module. I have created a test project in project -> project -> Projects.

I want to add team members for my project. When I click add button it shows only Administrator. I want to add my employee as team member. Why it takes only users as project team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly add employee in the team members of projects. Every employee created linked to user as show field in Employee Form "Related User". So for every employee must be a user you have to create, link that user with employee, and you have to add that user in team members.

You van not add directly employee in team member.

Hope this help

Regards,